# how to Access C function from SL4A python interpreter

Tags: android, sl4a

Any one please suggest, is it possible to access C function from python scripts in SL4A.
If so, how to create the shared library for the C files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you want, or at least I haven't searched for it long enough, but I think you can use this http://code.google.com/p/android-cruft/wiki/SL4AC, a library that is built to run C programs on Android phones, just like you would run Python.